# Why is name.map is not a function?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I try to map through an array and output it as a Dom element and it works perfectly, but I want to add a delete functionality to it so that I can delete which ever element with the corresponding id but for some reason when I hit the delete button it shows name.map IS NOT A FUNCTION I tried to get around this but it didn't work so install the REACT Extension from Chrome web store and when i open the developer tools in the Component i saw the delete button assign to each element and i can delete it from there but in the actual UI i can't WHY?

here is the code and a screenshot of the Dev tools

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function Deletecomponent() {

    const [name, setName] = useState([
        {
          text:'i am new here',
          author:'Hashim',
          id:1
        },
        {
          text:'i am new but not here',
          author:'Hashim',
          id:2
        },
        {
          text:'i am not new here',
          author:'Hashim',
          id:3
        },
  
      ]);
      
  
  
      const handleDelete = (id) => {
        const newName = name.filter(name => name.id !== id )
        setName({newName});
  
        console.log(id);
      }

    return (
        <div className='content'>
            
        {name.map(name => (
            <div>
           <h2>{name.text}</h2>
            <p>{name.author}</p>
            <button onClick={()=> handleDelete(name)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
            ))};

        </div>
    )
}

export default Deletecomponent
```

[image]

Comment: `setName({newName});` So `name` is now an object, not an array. You can't call `.map` on a non-array object.

Comment: so what's the solution, how do i update setName

Comment: By passing `newName` instead of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating the state invariant from array to object. Objects are not iterable and have no inherent `map` function. Since `name` is now an object, the `map` property is undefined and not a function, thus the error.

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
  const newName = name.filter(name => name.id !== id )
  setName({newName}); // <-- now an object!
}
```

You should maintain it as an array, return the filtered array as the next state value.

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
  setName(name => name.filter(el => el.id !== id));
}
```

You need to also set a React key on each mapped element and pass the `id` property to the delete handler as well, so the filtering can work correctly. The key is necessary for React's reconciliation so it can identify what did, or didn't, change in the UI and what can be potentially bailed on when rerendering.

```
{name.map(name => (
  <div key={name.id}> // <-- React key
    <h2>{name.text}</h2>
    <p>{name.author}</p>
    <button onClick={()=> handleDelete(name.id)}> // <-- pass id
      Delete
    </button>
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: Now the Error is gone but when I click nothing Happens it wont delete, and I add a console.log just below and when I click I can see the element that is been clicked

Comment: @HashimAliyuHashim You are missing the React key on each mapped element so React knows what was removed or changed in the array as it's rerendering.

Answer (score 0):

You have a conflict variable names. In your case, name is an array, but is override by a object. Just use a different name for a variable "name".

Suggestion: Use "names" for array, and "name" for a single object.